# SQLite database refuses to update and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sql-update

I'm using these two methods in order to update the balance of a bank app I'm writing, but the database refuses to update and I'm not sure why.

Function for getting how much to add:

```
public void addIncome(String cardNum,Scanner scanner){
    System.out.println("Enter income: ");
    int income = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    dataBase.addBalance(income,cardNum);
}
```

Prepared statement and function for query:

```
private final String ADD_BALANCE = ("UPDATE card SET balance=balance+? WHERE number=?");

public void addBalance(int amount, String number){
       try (Connection con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
         final var sql = con.prepareStatement(ADD_BALANCE)){
           sql.setInt(1, amount);
           sql.setString(2,number);
           sql.executeUpdate();
       }catch (SQLException throwables) {
           throwables.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: If `getConnection` returns a transaction-oriented connection then you need to commit after the update. But if auto-commit is enabled, then the problem is elsewhere. Do this: (a) check the balance before leaving the `try` and then check the balance again after returning from `addBalance`, then you'll know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a call to [`commit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit--), meaning the transaction will implicitly rollback when the connection is closed (at the end of the `try`).

```
try (Connection con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
     final var sql = con.prepareStatement(ADD_BALANCE)) {
    sql.setInt(1, amount);
    sql.setString(2, number);
    sql.executeUpdate();
    con.commit(); // HERE
}
```

Comment: By default, a data source needs to return a connection that is in auto-commit mode.